# Installing new packages in anaconda navigator [Unsatisfiable Error]

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I am a newbie to python, and was using spyder via anaconda. I am trying to use some packages i.e. pdfplumber, pymupdf, camelot-py etc in spyder but I was stuck at the stage to install the packages.

This is the steps that I have been tried before:

1. Install the packages via anaconda navigator: Go to Environment --> search the uninstalled category for the required packages --> tick the packages and click "apply"
2. Install packages via command through terminal and Ananconda Prompt --> I tried the codes below:

   conda install pdfplumber

   conda install -c conda-forge pdfplumber

   conda install pip --> then "pip install pdfplumber"
3. Also, I had tried to create another conda virtual environment and tried to install the packages under specific environment instead of the root (base).

However, all of the approaches above failed and I had get the several errors, one of the error message as below:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested Package -\> Available versions

Package setuptools conflicts for:
camelot-py -\> matplotlib-base \[version='\>=2.2.3'\] -\> setuptools\[version='\>=60.0.0'\] python=3.9 -\> pip -\> setuptools

Package pypy3.9 conflicts for:
pdfplumber -\> pillow\[version='\>=9.1'\] -\> pypy3.8\[version='\>=7.3.8.*|7.3.9.*'|\>=7.3.9'\]
camelot-py -\> chardet\[version='\>=9.1'\] -\> pypy3.8\[version='\>=7.3.8.*|7.3.9.*'|\>=7.3.9'\]
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
\-camelot-py -\> click\[version='\>=6.7'\] -\> \_win

Your installed version is: not available

Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

May I know what should be the correct procedure to install new packages in conda? As I really tried to research many use case online but still getting stuck at this stage.

Really hope to get some advice from you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using pypy, not a CPython-based verson of Python.
Not all packages support / have a (or the correct) pypy version and thus cannot be used in your environment.